# Unecessarily large column widths in HTML tables published by R Quarto when the table header contains special characters

Tags: html, r, quarto

All,

I am trying to render an HTML table in R Quarto of with a header that contains special characters. I can render the table correctly correctly by specifying the characters in HTML and passing `escape=FALSE` to `knitr::kable()`. However, the column width in the final column is based upon the width of the raw characters, not the number final rendered characters.

For example, the following code

```r
#| eval: true

dof <- c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 1000, 10000)
df <- crossing(df1 = dof, df2 = dof) |> 
  mutate(fval = qf(0.05, df1, df2, lower.tail=FALSE)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=df2, values_from=fval)

knitr::kable(df, digits = 2, escape=FALSE,
    col.names=c("&nu;<sub>1</sub> / &nu;<sub>2</sub>", tail(colnames(df),-1)))
```

renders as

[image: Rendered table with first column width much wider than rendered content]

with an unnecessarily large column one width, because the column width is determined by the number of raw characters `&nu;<sub>1</sub> / &nu;<sub>2</sub>` and not the number of rendered characters ν<sub>1</sub> / ν<sub>2</sub>:

[image: Rendered table showing reason for extra wide first column]

Is there a way to get the HTML column widths to automatically-resize to the rendered content?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out `reactable`:

````
---
format: html
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dof <- c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 1000, 10000)
df <- crossing(df1 = dof, df2 = dof) |> 
  mutate(fval = qf(0.05, df1, df2, lower.tail=FALSE)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=df2, values_from=fval)

reactable::reactable(df, 
                     defaultColDef = reactable::colDef(
    format = reactable::colFormat(digits = 1),
    align = "center",
    minWidth = 70,
    headerStyle = list(background = "#f7f7f8")
  ),
                     columns = list(
  df1 = reactable::colDef(name = "&nu;<sub>1</sub> / &nu;<sub>2</sub>", html = TRUE)
))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Julian. I can verify this works. You don't know of any way to do this within `kable` + `kableExtra` do you?